# Partition a linked list around a value x

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

In cracking the coding interview, the problem stated in the question is given. Both solutions the author proposes involve creating a new linked list, resulting in O(N) time and O(N) space. She refers to these solutions as optimal, and I'm not sure why. Isn't it possible to do the partitioning of a random-ordered linked list such that all nodes less than x come before all nodes greater than or equal to x in O(N) time but O(1) space?

The author proposed two solutions. One was to create two linked lists, each linked list has nodes with values greater than/equal to node and the other has nodes with values less than. After populating, she merged the list.

Her other solution was to create a new linked list and iterate through the linked list passed to the method-- those values greater than or equal to x were appended to tail node for new linked list, those values less than x were placed before head node. Both of these, I believe, are O(N) time and space.

The code that I implemented (hoping it's correct!) simply deletes a node that is less than x and moves it toward the head of the linked list. I believe that's O(N) time and O(1) space but I doubt that I'm proposing an algorithm more efficient than what the author proposed. Please let me know if I'm overlooking something! Code below:

```
def partition(head, val)
  return nil if head.nil? || val.nil?
  node = head 
  if node.val < val 
    min_node = node 
  end 

  until node.next.nil?
    if node.next < val 
      #delete next node, so..
      removed_node = node.next 
      node.next = node.next.next 

      if min_node.nil?  #then head wasn't smaller than val
        min_node = removed_node 
        min_node.next = head 
      else 
        removed_node.next = min_node 
        min_node = removed_node 
      end
    else 
      node = node.next 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Naive answer : Space complexity of a linked-list is O(n) http://bigocheatsheet.com/. You still have n nodes after the partition, n-1 nodes if you remove x.

Comment: Looks fine. But in general, whether the input data is mutable or not should be given as part of the question. If it isn't, the first thing to do is find out. Certainly you'd be concerned with that in a real design.